# SOAP::Lite sending wrong Envelope namespace?

Tags: perl, soap

I'm trying to send a message to a SOAP service and getting an error:

`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/", the namespace on the "Envelope" element, is not a valid SOAP version.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

My code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';

use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'all';

my %data = (
    ...
);

my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('file:wsdl.txt'); 
$service->...(
    SOAP::Data->name('userId')->value('...'),
    SOAP::Data->name('password')->value('...'),
    map( SOAP::Data->name($_)->value($data{$_})->type('string'), sort keys %data )
);
```

SOAP::Lite version is 1.09.

Comment: What namespace URL is it sending?

Comment: The response suggests the root element SOAP::Lite created was a `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/}Envelope`. It should be `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope` Could you confirm which one SOAP::Lite used?

Comment: I'd like to see `wsdl.txt`. I bet something in there is confusing SOAP::Lite. It's not a very robust module. In fact, I think I've heard of this before. Check if `wsdl.txt` uses the `soap` prefix. If so, renaming that prefix should do the trick.

Comment: @ysth, Did you get anywhere?

Comment: @ikegami: yes, it seems like the whole `->service` approach doesn't really work.  maybe this is an area where SOAP::Lite doesn't really support soap 1.1.  I will post what I ended up with within the next few days.

Comment: Changing `soap` for a different prefix in `wsdl.txt` didn't help? Dang. I was sure I remembered that being the problem.

Comment: you mean the `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"`?  I didn't try that.  I will try to post an MCVE too if I have time